# Android: Fill Listview with a by code generated Layout

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater

I got the following two problems: 
1. I want to fill a ListView with elements, but i got different layouts for each item.
2. I generate these different layouts by code. (The exspected parameters include an int of the resource, but I only have an object as Layout)

As a result of my lack of knowledge concerning Inflaters and Listviews I dunno how to continue here.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is easy, is adapter's problem what layout to inflate based on item type. The second problem is again fairly simple, simply use a LinearLayout, or a RelativeLayout or any Layout that you like as a container, and add your object to this layout. I use this for a recycler view showing a chat, where some items are text, and others are images.